# jsr 303 validate a number and auto initialize to 0

Tags: java, bean-validation

in my domain class I have an integer which is being populated from
form. if user enters any digit , it will be validated and if he leaves
the input box empty, it will default initialize to 0

so far I have done the first part with

```
@NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER)
```

How to go about default initilizing it to 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If youfr probldem is that the default value is 0 when the user does not enter anything in the box, set a validator for the accepted range, and initialize it to a number outside that range. If all numbers are acceptable, change it from an int to an Integer, and use @NotNull.

Answer (score 2):

How about assigning the field an initial value?

If the field is of type `int` it automatically has a value of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
validation rules
private int numberToValidate = 0;
```